# Is it bad practice to append style tag with multiple styles via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question regarding style tags and Javascript. Many plugins or scripts come with a separate CSS file for styling. So, is it bad practice to avoid this, and use a style tag and append it to the head of the page, to then use those styles for your plugin?

For example, this code:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';

style.innerHTML = '.hg-grid-item-4{ width: calc(24.25% - '+Options.padding * 2+'px); padding: '+Options.padding+'px; float: left; margin-bottom: 1%}';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

would add some styling to the website without needing an external CSS stylesheet. Would this cause problems in older browsers?

Also, as you can see in my example, I used a variable for the padding and the width. Is there a way of doing this if you dedice to use an external CSS? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No problem for the old browser. Maybe just `calc` feature. If you are adding styles dynamically you can calculate proper values in javascript

Comment: Make sure that if you do then you use class names that are very specific/unique so you don't conflict with other packages.

Comment: It's not "bad practice," especially if you NEED to use JavaScript variables. You'll save an HTTP request, a nominal savings.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: If you really want to do this, which I can't recommend, I would prefer to use CSSOM.

Answer (score 0):

- In most of the cases you do not need calc() in CSS - this will always slow things down a bit and in general is an over complication that can almost always be done in a more simple way
- Doing things the way you did doesn't consider a non-js version. So not the best practice especially when you style something like .hg-grid-item-4 so I assume some some grid that you use. Will this not break badly with JS disabled ?
- It makes the code less maintainable - not sure what would be the reason to mix logic with styling ? In general it is a better idea to use Sass for example and define your Options.padding there if this is not something that really really needs to be calculated with JS. Does it ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the style tag to the DOM with JavaScript is totally legal for JavaScript to do, however, this is not considered "best practice."

When writing code, it best to separate the view from your application logic. The easiest way to do this is to put all of your styles in a CSS file. Also, it has the added benefit of making your code easier for other developers to understand.

For more information:

- [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)
- [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

In regards to your variable padding question, in vanilla CSS, this is not possible, in order to use variables in CSS, you would need to use a CSS Preprocessor, like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). However, I think this would be overkill for your problem, you can make flexible styles using Flexbox or using percents instead of fixed margins or padding.

Comment: In my case, it's just a script I made for simplificating the columns problem, because I always find myself doing the same thing over and over again, I thought it would be smart to create a 'plugin'? to make it easier. So now, I can just make: myDiv.columnify(); and set the options there, where I have the padding, the breakpoints and the amount of columns.